# Using and assign variables of other file (package) in go

Tags: mongodb, variables, go, global-variables

I have a http server using mongodb as a backend db, I wrapped the db operations in a separate file (*package*), and I don't want to make a connection every time, So I think make a **global** session and copy it like [this](https://gist.github.com/ardan-bkennedy/9198289#file-gomgosample-full-go-L95) maybe a good idea. So this is so far I've got:

File `server.go` in which I start the http server, and I also want to init the mongodb connection from here, for I don't know other way to make a connection that could live through the whole life of the http server so far :-(

```
package main

import(
    "./mylib"
    "net/http"
)
...
func main(){
    dbutil.MySession, err := dbutil.ConnectDb()
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    // I will just omit the http server config code for convenience
    http.HandleFunc(...)
    http.HandleFunc(...)
}
...
```

And here is the file `dbutil.go` which contains the variable `MySession`. By the way, the total dir structure of them is like this, should be fine:

```
.
├── mylib
│   └── dbutil.go
└── server.go
```

And in `dbutil.go`:

```
package dbutil
import (
  ...
)

var MySession *mgo.Session
func ConnectDb() (*mgo.Session, error){
   session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
   if err != nil {
       return nil, err
   }
   return session, nil
}
```

But when I compile them and run the server, it complains that:

```
# command-line-arguments
./server.go:28: cannot declare name dbutil.MySession
```

I notice that if I change `dbutil.MySession, err := dbutil.ConnectDb()` to `dbutil.MySession, err = dbutil.ConnectDb()` things will not work either.

So How Can I assign the **global** Variable `MySession` in this case? Or did I do something wrong (*try to use a variable of other file*) at the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) `:=` creates new variables. The name of the new variables cannot contain package names, but yours does:

```
dbutil.MySession, err := dbutil.ConnectDb()
```

Just don't use the short variable declaration:

```
var err error
dbutil.MySession, err = dbutil.ConnectDb()
// ...rest of your code
```

Comment: Aha.. not again, falling into the pitfall of `:=` and `=` one more time. Thanks, things works now.